Issue with Adding Image using Tailwind CSS: Module Not Found Error
enter image description hereWhen I try to add an image using Tailwind CSS with @extend, I encounter the error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './public/img/header-img.jpg'. How can I resolve this issue?
I'm attempting to add an image from my project to a component using Tailwind CSS, but even though I've correctly specified the directory where the image is located, I still receive this error.
Here's the code snippet I'm trying to use:
    import React from 'react'

const Random = () => {
  return (
    <div className='bg-main-image'></div>
  )
}

export default Random
       
    tailwind.config.js =>
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container:{
      center: true,
    },
    extend: {
      colors:{
        "header-color":"#0E46A3",
        "find-color":"#202528",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
         'main-image':"url('./public/img/header-img.jpg')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Operating System: Windows 10
Tailwind CSS Version: Current
Here are the troubleshooting steps I've tried so far:
Ensured that the file path of the image is correct.
Checked the project directory structure and made sure the image is in the correct folder.
Verified that the filename and extension of the image are correct.
Could you please assist me in resolving this error? Thank you in advance.
